# Can't reply or create new email in GMail

Tags: firefox, gmail

Lately I've noticed that I can't compose a new email, nor reply to an email using the GMail web interface.  I run GMail in a private browsing tab/window in Firefox 56.02 on Windows 7 64.  I also tried Firefox ESR 52.6 on windows 10 64 Enterprise with a similar set of security extensions and got the same result.  No decentralyes though, as its not compatible.

For a long time I didn't send much email, but lately I've started using email again and this is becoming bothersome.  I found that if I use the [HTML view](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049?hl=en), I can compose and reply.  However, the modern view gives me the problem.  There is no longer a way to force GMail to use HTML view all the time, though as recently as a few years ago, if you used it more than a few times, you would be given the option to permanently switch.  On a side note, GMail consumes about 100 - 120mb of RAM per tab, while HTML view uses 5 - 15mb per tab.

I found a variety of people complaining about this issue over the years, but no solutions or things to try to fix.  2008, 2010, and 2014 come to mind, though it was the other day when I searched for a solution.  Regardless, any fixes from more than a year or two ago won't even apply, and I did not find anything recent.

I do use a variety of security minded extensions to keep Google's (and others) tentacle's at bay.  [Noscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) is allowing all scripts on the page, though I am using [Decentralyes](https://decentraleyes.org) to replace some javascript so that I don't leak IP address information.  What it does in a nutshell:

> Protects you against tracking through "free", centralized, content
>   delivery. It prevents a lot of requests from reaching networks like
>   Google Hosted Libraries, and serves local files to keep sites from
>   breaking. Complements regular content blockers.

I'd drop GMail if I could, but I have not found a suitable alternative.

Since GMail is a web app, what can I even check; how can I try to fix it?

Comment: Your sentiments regarding Firefox Quantum are well-established.  However, it may prove difficult to troubleshoot new problems when you are utilizing a version of the browser that doesn't receive bug fixes or security updates. Have you considered testing your Gmail on a machine that is running Firefox 52 ESR to see if that alleviates the problem?  That version will still be supported for another six months.

Comment: I tried Firefox ESR 52.6 with a similar set of security extensions and got the same result.  No decentralyes though, as its not compatible.

Comment: Decentraleyes only caches the javascript files, it supposedly doesn't change them. I'd suspect Noscript instead. Can you send e-mails with Noscript turned off completely?

Comment: I'll try disabling NoScript to see if that has an effect.  I suspect it's the private browsing mode that's throwing a kink in things though.

Answer (score 0):

Not really answering the question, just providing a workaround:

You seem to have a misconception about Gmail. It's not only a webapp, it also supports standard mailing protocols like POP3 and [IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en). You can use it from your favourite e-mail client as well. (Personally I use it from Thunderbird through IMAP without any problems.) If your privacy settings gave you problems with the web interface, but you didn't want to compromise, then you could still try if you liked this setup better.

Comment: I'm OK with a workaround.  I tried Thunderbird a while back and it wasn't suited to what I wanted to do (use it with work email too).  I never got around to find another email client either.